# Mocking Interfaces with Kotlin and Mockito

Tags: mockito, kotlin

I don't really understand interface mocking in Kotlin. I'm not sure if this is Kotlin specific or applies to java also. So far I have only tried it in Kotlin.

I have a mocked class with interfaces:

```
val mockObj = mock(MyClass::class.java, withSettings().extraInterfaces(IMyInterface::class.java)
```

now, this produces the following problem in IntelliJ:

```
`when`(mockObj.someMethod()).thenReturn(0.1)
```

the `someMethod()` will be *red* (I assume this depends on the color scheme, but you get the idea - a problem: *unresolved reference*)

to solve this, I simply include this line before it:

```
val mockInterface = mockObj as IMyInterface
```

the mockInterface will be grey squigly underlined because it is *never used*. I still use `mockObj` for the `when`

however, this makes the *red* disappear

I'm not sure why this works... can someone explain the theory?

to get rid of the grey underline, I then remove `val mockInterface =`

so my magic line is reduced to `mockObj as IMyInterface`

Comment: to be absolutely clear, the reason I'm confused is _because I created a new variable I never used_ - to solve the problem... and even more confusingly,  I then removed the left hand of the assignment and it still works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of `mock(MyClass::class.java)` is `MyClass`. The returned object is also an instance of IMyInterface, since you asked that to Mockito, but the Kotlin compiler can't know that.

`mockObj as IMyInterface` tells the Kotlin compiler to cast mockObj to IMyInterface. Since the Kotlin compiler supports [smart casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html), it knows that, if this line doesn't throw any exception, then `mockObj` is an instance of IMyInterface. And it thus lets you call `someMethod()`, and inserts the necessary cast for you.

You can replicate this with a simpler example:

```
val foo: Any = "hello"
val bar = foo as String
println(foo.length) // smart cast added here
```

You could also use the `is` operator to make the compiler insert a smart cast

```
val foo: Any = "hello"
if (foo is String) {
    println(foo.length) // smart cast added here
}
```

Comment: p.s. changing it to `is` and assigning that to a variable doesn't work for me - but `as` is good enough